# Convert PKCS'11 Object handle to X509Certificate Object in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

How can i convert the Object_Handle which is a ulong returned by C_FindObject to a X509Certificate object in C#.  Here is the code .

```
ulong[] foundObjectIds = new ulong[10];
foundObjectIds[0] = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
success = PKCS11CsharpWrapper.C_FindObjects(session, foundObjectIds, Convert.ToUInt64(foundObjectIds.Length), ref foundObjectCount);
```

Now i have to convert foundObjectIds[0]  to a X509Certificate object .

I tried the below way and it doesn't work for me .

```
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ulong)));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(foundObjectIds[0], ptr, false);
IntPtr[] arr = new IntPtr[2];
Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, 1);
X509Certificate2 cert= new X509Certificate2((IntPtr)foundObjectIds[0]);
```

Comment: Take a look on my answer about Pkcs11X509store: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72376132/1382345 It provides code to retrieve a X509Certificate2 from a Pkcs11 capable device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object handle cannot be converted to `X509Certificate2` object. You need to read the value of `CKA_VALUE` attribute of the certificate object using `C_GetAttributeValue` function. `CKA_VALUE` attribute contains DER encoded certificate which can be passed as `byte[]` into the constructor of `X509Certificate2` class.

BTW if you are using [Pkcs11Interop](http://pkcs11interop.net/) library then why are you working with `LowLevelAPI` instead of `HighLevelAPI`?

Comment: I recently come across this PKCS11 interop .Before that my prototype is based on the lowlevel api . I just started replacing them with the highlevel api .But in both cases it returns a IntPtr . I try to copy the contents to a byte[] and try to use that to initialize X509Certifcate .But i get error. "Byte Array cannot be converted to X509Certificate"